# Gyro controls in Unity (Android) - setting an initial offset OR achieving consistent results with rotationRateUnbiased

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, gyroscope

I want my game's control scheme to assume the position in which the phone is held at the start of the game as the default around which the gyroscope then rotates around. As far as I can tell, there are two ways to achieve this, and neither of them seem to be working. As long as I can get one of them to work, I'll be satisfied.

Just in case it becomes relevant, my Unity version is 2021.3.6f1 and I'm testing on a Samsung A52. I'm using the old Input Manager because the new Input System Package didn't seem to work for my device.

#### Approach 1 -

Rotating the player with the delta of the rotation instead of the actual value, using

```
transform.Rotate(Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased);
```

The issue here is that the numbers quickly seem to stop adding up, meaning you can hold your phone in a specific position, shake it for a few seconds, return it to said position and then find your character in a completely different rotation than before. The more axes you rotate your phone around and the faster you do it, the worse the problem gets.
I have tried multiplying the *rotationRateUnbiased* by *Time.fixedDeltaTime* or setting *Input.gyro.Input.gyro.updateInterval* to the same number as my fixed update interval, but the problem remained unaffected. Trying out similar variables like *rotationRate* didn't make a difference either.

#### Approach 2 -

Here I would use the actual rotation and then somehow adjust it using the initial rotation of the phone. I tried using several examples given by other users in previous questions about gyro controls, but none of them produced the entire outcome. In essence it boils down to something like the following:

```
//when activating the gyro sensor
defaultRotation = Input.gyro.attitude; 

//in fixedUpdate
Quaternion offsetRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(defaultRotation) * Input.gyro.attitude; 
transform.rotation = initialRotationOfPlayer * offsetRotation;
```

Needless to add, this method doesn't work for me at all. I know there must be some way to do this, but so far I wasn't able to figure it out.